# While Copying plist to somewhere else filetype getting changed

Tags: java

I am interested in copying the plist from my application to somewhere in the folder. I am trying but that file's type getting changed **Unix Executable file to Document** Is there a way to programmatically copy the file without changing file type ?

Can any body help me ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What OS are you trying to do this on?  Can you post the code that is giving trouble?

Comment: Also ... what is telling you that the file's type was "Unix Executable" and is now "Document"?

Comment: Can any body know the utility which copy file same as it is with same extension type on mac os

Answer (score 0):

No I am not changing the name of file, i am copying file as it is to another location.
I have java application which i am running on MAC os, and i am using following

```
            FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                   if (pathname.getAbsolutePath().indexOf(File.separator + "data") != -1) {
                        return false;
                    } else if (pathname.getAbsolutePath().indexOf(File.separator + "Logs") != -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                        return true;
                    } 
            };
```

FileUtils.copyDirectory("source path", "destination path",filter );

While is tried manually copy-paste on mac for same file (plist) that is same as source file with Unix Executable file extension

Answer (score 0):

Your OS may be using the execute bit to determine if the file is an executable vs. a document.
Try changing the execute bit of the file...

```
chmod a+x {filename}
```